# What is the correct pointer type conversion for C floats in Racket?

Tags: lisp, racket

In the Racket documentation there are integer pointer types like _intptr, but how do I use float* from, let's say, a dynamic C library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Racket has built-in `_float` (and `_double`) C type representations, and also a `_pointer` type. You can combine these to treat a return value as a C `float` pointer.

Something along these lines (this is a sketch - modify as needed to suit your situation):

Your C function:

```
float* my_float_returner() {
    float* pi = malloc(sizeof(float));
    *pi = 3.1415926535;
    return pi;
}
```

And the Racket FFI wrapper:

```
(require ffi/unsafe
         ffi/unsafe/define)

;; not strictly necessary, but probably a good reminder for yourself
(define _float-ptr _pointer)

;; registers the library and sets up the function to define interfaces to its contents
(define-ffi-definer define-my-lib (ffi-lib "my_library_path"))

;; defines the interface to your C function
(define-my-lib my_float_returner (_fun -> _float-ptr))

;; returns a _float object containing the dereferenced value returned by
;; my_float_returner
(ptr-ref (my_float_returner) _float)
```

---

Needless to say, treating pointers as untyped this way **can be dangerous**, and you have to be careful.

I'll go so far as to quote the [Racket foreign function interface documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/intro.html)'s very first sentence:

> Although using the FFI requires writing no new C code, it provides very little
>   insulation against the issues that C programmers face related to safety and memory
>   management.

If you use these tools, you should have your C hat on, with all of the pointer-related <s>paranoia</s> care and thoughtfulness that comes with it.